# Difference between thin-plate and willmore energy

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

The **thin-plate** energy functional is defined by :
$$
E = \int \kappa_1^2 + \kappa_2^2
$$
while the **Willmore** energy functional is defined by :
$$
W = \int (\kappa_1 - \kappa_2)^2 
$$

For a closed surface, if we develop $W$:
$$
W = \int \kappa_1^2 + \kappa_2^2 - 2\int K = E  -4\pi\chi
$$
where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic of the surface that appears following the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

In conclusion, for a closed surface, the thin-plate and the Willmore energies differ by $4\pi\chi$.

**Is it correct?**

If we look at the Euler-Lagrange equations related to these energies we have :
$$
\Delta^2 f = 0
$$
for the thin-plate energy, and :
$$
\Delta H + 2H(H^2-K) = 0
$$
for the Willmore energy.

But since these energies differ by a topological invariant of the surface, a critical point of one energy would be also critical for the other, which means the Euler-Lagrange equations above are equivalent.

**Where am I wrong ?**

Comment: What is $f$?  Can't make much progress without knowing that . . .

Comment: It's the surface : the map on which E(f) and W(f) are computed. The values k1, k2, H and K are the principal, mean and gaussian curvatures of the surface f.

Comment: So to be more precise, is the surface given as $z = f(x, y)$ or as $f(x, y, z) = 0$?  I am inclined towards the latter since $z = f(x, y)$ is topologically restrictive.

Comment: It's a 2D surface in 3D : $f(u,v) = [ x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v) ]$. But the simpler case $z = f(x,y)$ is also interesting since any 3D surface can be locally seen as the graph of such function.

Comment: You imply  differential area $E = \int (\kappa_1^2 + \kappa_2^2)\, dA$  etc?

Comment: Yes. I omitted $dA$ in my equations but it is here in every integral

Comment: At least the last equaton should fully include area and  bending modulus

Answer (score 1):

The biharmonic equation $\Delta^2 f = 0$ is NOT the Euler-Lagrange equation related to the energy defined by that first integral you posted.

Rather, it's what you get when you apply a thin plate approximation: $\nabla f \approx 0$. Under that, $\kappa_1^2 + \kappa_2^2 \approx f_{xx}^2 + 2 f_{xy}^2 + f_{yy}^2$. Applying Euler-Lagrange to that last expression leads to the (notably linear) biharmonic equation.